# Have MC Java edition, want to use Windows 10 edition for cross-play

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I have MC Java edition but I also want to cross-play with my friend on xbox.

I know that you can redeem a free code for MC Windows 10 edition but when I try to redeem it it won't give me a code it'll just redirect me to the store where I can buy MC Windows 10 edition.

Help? As far as I know I'm doing it correctly...

Comment: could you share screenshots of you problem? I have problems recreating the behaviour you are experiencing

Comment: When did you buy the java edition? If I remember correctly you can only get the windows 10 edition for free if your account had been created before a certain year. I'm not quite sure though.

Comment: Oh yeah correct. The date was : October 19th, 2018 if you bought Java Edition after that, you will not get the free code https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2064007-minecraft-for-windows-10

Comment: You cannot get MCPE for free anymore, that offer has expired. Also, it's a completely different game, you have to be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to had bought the game before a certain date (Oct. 19th 2018) for the code.

Comment: I downvoted due to the "idk what it is" phrase. The date is mentioned in the question's comments: Oct 19, 2018. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359339/have-mc-java-edition-want-to-use-windows-10-edition-for-cross-play#comment507864_359339 Could you edit your post so it includes this information?